# javascript find an object with specific properties in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to make an extension to existing code, can't change it.
There's this array:

```
var availableTags = [
        { label: "Yoga classes", category: "EDUCATIONAL" },
        { label: "Cooking classes", category: "EDUCATIONAL" },
        { label: "Cheese tastings", category: "EDUCATIONAL" },
        { label: "Maker Workshops", category: "PRACTICAL" },
        { label: "Seminars", category: "PRACTICAL" },
        //many more of these
];
```

Now I need to check if a text entered in an input box is included in one of the labels, e.g. if the user enters "Yoga classes" => OK, if "Yoga" => NOK, "sdsdf" => NOK, etc.

What is the best way to do this? I am not sure I can use Array.indexOf as I am not sure how to pass the Object to the function, I would try looping through the array (around 40 entries) and compare each object.

Comment: You're gonna have to loop through the array and check each object, then stop when you find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

> Tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Then your code would look something like:

```
var isFound = availableTags.some(function(el) {
    return el.label === 'Yoga classes';
});
```

*Note: [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method needs to be shimmed.*

Comment: You'll have to run that test on every single obj in the array until it finds the positive case - perf will be poor, especially on larger arrays.

Comment: But it is a very elegant one :) Agreed with the performance issue. 40 entries are not exceedingly many, so I think I can live with this.

Comment: `some` will not check all the objects, only until callback returns true.

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop over every item in `availableTags` and check whether that item's `label` is equal to some input. Try something like this:

```
var input = "Yoga classes";
var found = false;
for (var i = 0, j = availableTags.length; i < j; i++) {
    var cur = availableTags[i];
    if (cur.label === input) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(found);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/k4cp4/4/

Where this can easily be put into a function, like:

```
var checkMatch = (function () {
    var availableTags = [
        { label: "Yoga classes", category: "EDUCATIONAL" },
        { label: "Cooking classes", category: "EDUCATIONAL" },
        { label: "Cheese tastings", category: "EDUCATIONAL" },
        { label: "Maker Workshops", category: "PRACTICAL" },
        { label: "Seminars", category: "PRACTICAL" }
    ];

    return function (input) {
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0, j = availableTags.length; i < j; i++) {
            var cur = availableTags[i];
            if (cur.label === input) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    };
})();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/k4cp4/5/

This checks for an exact match. So if you want a case insensitive match, you can use:

```
if (cur.label.toLowerCase() === input.toLowerCase()) {
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/k4cp4/6/

If you want to see if any of the `label`s **contain** the input, you can use `indexOf` like:

```
if (cur.label.indexOf(input) > -1) {
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/k4cp4/7/

Comment: I recant. Looping is the fastest. Array.indexOf also performs a loop, but it adds additional overhead of type checking and some other stuff. The latest Chrome seems to optimize for indexOf in large arrays, but that optimization is not consistent in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var check = function(item) {    
    for(at in availableTags) {
       if(item == availableTags[at].label) {
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}


console.log(check("Yoga classes"));
```