# function always returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fairly new to Javascript, could anybody tell me why this simple array loop / string comparison function always returns false? They're both of type string and the data is the same, the loop should absolutely return true. Possible syntax error? Also is there an easier way of running this check.

```
function imageDuplicate(fileName)
{
    $.each(previewImagesArray, function(index)
    {
        if(previewImagesArray[index].name == fileName)
            return true;
    });
    return false
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'll be faster and less code if you just use a `for` statement. `for (var i = 0, a = previewImagesArray; i < a.length; ++i) if (a[i].name === fileName) return true; return false;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are returning true from the the anonymous inner function, not from `imageDuplicate`, instead use a flag variable as shown below

```
function imageDuplicate(fileName) {
    var valid = false;
    $.each(previewImagesArray, function (index) {
        if (previewImagesArray[index].name == fileName) {
            valid = true;
            //to stop the iteration
            return false
        }
    });
    return valid
}
```

Comment: @Spark: If this answer solve your problem, please "Accept" it as the right answer.

Answer (score 8):

How about this instead:

```
function imageDuplicate(fileName)
{
   return  previewImagesArray.some(function(item)
    {
        return item.name === fileName;
    });
}
```

**Important:** this will work on IE9+ if you need this to run in older version of IE please follow the polyfill instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Other post samples:

[javascript find an object with specific properties in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339635/javascript-find-an-object-with-specific-properties-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

The code inside `function(index)` is a separate function, nested inside `imageDuplicate`. The return value of that function would be processed by `.each()` as it sees fit.

As such, the only statement which returns from your outer function is your `return false`.

As other answers are illustrating in code, you can declare a variable in the scope of `imageDuplicate` and have the inner function access and modify that value in order to get the effect you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment
 *returning from each loop, doesn't return from function.*

Try something like this

```
function imageDuplicate(fileName)
{
    var isDuplicate = false;
    $.each(previewImagesArray, function(index)
    {
        if(previewImagesArray[index].name == fileName){
            isDuplicate = true;
            return false; //exit from each loop
       }
    });
    return isDuplicate; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one tweak would be to use the value directly

```
    $.each(previewImagesArray, function (index, value) {
        if (value.name == fileName) {
            ...
        }
    });
```