# Checking whether key and value exist in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

Suppose I have:

```
var original = {

    0: {
        id : 158    
    },
    1: {
        id : 159    
    }

}

var newSeries = {

    0: {
        id : 158,
        name: "Jason",
        lastname: "Smith",
        status : "active"   
    },
    1: {
        id : 159    ,
        name: "Rebecca",
        lastname: "Smith",
        status : "terminated"   
    }

}
```

and I want to know for example `id` # 158 from `newSeries` exists in `original`, how would I go about doing so? I found a partial solution to use the `in` operator but that only compares their keys and not the keys and values.

Comment: In your loop, if the key is `in`, then check the value at `newSeries[i]['id']`

Comment: Given the way your data is currently structured, there's no other way to find the id value other than the brute force way of iterating all the keys and checking for an id match.  You could restructure your data to add an index by id to allow a direct id lookup if needed.

Comment: You can use an array and http://stackoverflow.com/q/16339635/218196. Either way, what *exactly* are you having problems with? You must have tried something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to loop through each keys and values to test if id is there.

For instance

```
var myId = 158;
for (var key in original) {
    if (original[key].id === myId) {
        // here your id has been found
    }
}
```

If you don't want to loop through your object like this, you will have to change your data structure a bit. You could use ids as a key in your original object and search it like this:

```
var original = {

    158: {
        id : 158    
    },
    159: {
        id : 159    
    }
};

var myId = 158;

if (myId in original) {
    // here your id has been found
}
```

Comment: I found this to be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you planning to do lots of processing like that, I would commend using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/). It has methods for finding values by passing lamda function, filtering, sorting, merging, converitng and lots of other functionality

With underscorejs its one liner:

```
_(original).find(function(x) { return x.id == 159; })
```

[Jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/resayoyi/4/edit?html,output)

Comment: This is interesting, though this doesn't return a boolean, but another object that matches the ID we're looking for.

Comment: just add !! in front to get boolean

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (var n in newSeries) {
   console.log('id ' + 
               newSeries[n].id + 
               ' exists: ' +
               (original[n].id === newSeries[n].id));   
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w78B/5/)

Comment: Why are you casting `original[n].id === newSeries[n].id` into a boolean when it's already a boolean expression?

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting ES5:

```
function isValueInObject(value, object) {

    return Object.keys(object).map(function (key) {
        return object[key];
    }).some(function (_value) { 
        return _value === value; 
    });

}

console.log(isValueInObject('bar', {foo: 'bar'})) // true
console.log(isValueInObject('baz', {foo: 'bar'})) // false
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttSLb/2/)