# How to find an object comprising multiple key/value pairs in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given:

```
var objects_found = [];
var entry = {any_number:77, any_text:"P1"}; // note: both primitive types
objects_found.push(entry);
```

.. why -with console logging showing such key/value pairs to be correctly stored- the following:

```
if (entry in objects_found) { ... }; // never fires
if (!(entry in objects_found)) { ... }; // always fires
```

Other than looping through the array as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339635/javascript-find-an-object-with-specific-properties-in-an-array)), is there a simple fix?

Comment: the keys in your 'entry' object should be strings like this: 'any_number': 77

Comment: the `in` operator finds indexes and properties, e.g. `'any_number' in entry` returns `true` as the object `entry` has the property `any_number`. It's not used for finding objects in arrays. AFAIK there is no way to magically pull a value out of an array without iterating over the array - even `indexOf` listed below will iterate over your array to find the index.

Comment: @Tarun - The property names `any_number` and `any_text` *are* strings whether you quote them or not.

Comment: Google "javascript in operator". That will lead you to this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in. There you will find it says "The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object". Not the **value** of the property, but the property itself.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the goal you have in mind here? It's a fairly rare situation where you would need to search for an object in an array when you have just pushed the object in the array yourself. Perhaps you were writing some simplified code as an example, which is a good thing, but I'm afraid there isn't enough detail about the actual goal of the code to give much relevant advice. If you can elaborate on what you're trying to do, it will help people help you.

Comment: @Michael Geary. Manually comparing two descrete d3.js selections (on curr and prev arrays - both vertical slices derived from progressing thru a time-based sequence), each comprising multiple elements and their (primitively typed) data items. Need to know which elements are sustained or repeated, which have expired and which are new. Effectively as d3.js's enter(), update(), exit() pattern, but with non-trivial data dependencies (such as d.duration values that can bridge not only the current timeslice, but, possibly, future ones. Likely outwith the d3.js pattern's scope.. All clear? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if (objects_found.indexOf(entry) !== -1) {
    // `entry` is in `objects_found`
} else {
    // not in the array
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toby3105/kad0mr7y/)